# what are the appropriate tense forms to be used in these sentences and why?

Tags: grammar, tense, past-tense, present-tense

> She promised me that she (to ring up) me as soon as she (to return) from London.
>
> She (to tell) me that the plane (to take off) at exactly 5 o'clock.
>
> I learned that she (to get) a parcel from her parents one of these days and (to be going) to tell her about it.

I think that there must be:

> She promised me that she would ring me up as soon as she returned from London.
>
> She told me that the plane takes off at exactly 5 o'clock.
>
> I learned that she will get a parcel from her parents one of these days and is going to tell her about it

but I'm not sure about the tenses with "as soon as". In the second one, I know that with the scheduled actions we use pr. simple but what about the first part where we have past simple? Is it possible to mix the tenses? And in the 3rd we have "learned" in past and then "these days" which is future.

Comment: You will get better responses if you tell us what you think so we can help you better. If you edit your question and say why you think what you think that would be best.

Comment: ok, thank you. I tried to

Answer (score 0):

A lot depends here on the overall context in which the sentences are found so for some of them there are several possibilities.

> She promised me that she (to ring up) me as soon as she (to return) from London.

Your suggestion is

> She promised me that she would ring me up as soon as she returned from London.

That seems fine. It would not be wrong to say *had returned*

> She (to tell) me that the plane (to take off) at exactly 5 o'clock.

Your suggestion

> She told me that the plane takes off at exactly 5 o'clock.

That is fine too as long as we are still before 5 o'clock. Otherwise you would say

> She told me that the plane would take off at exactly 5 o'clock.

It would also be correct there to say *was going to take off*.

> I learned that she (to get) a parcel from her parents one of these days and (to be going) to tell her about it.

Your suggestion here has gone a bit astray

> I learned that she will get a parcel from her parents one of these days and is going to tell her about it

I think the meaning here is that the other person does not know yet about her parcel so it is more likely to be

> I learned that she will get a parcel from her parents one of these days and I am going to tell her about it

Comment: She told me that  the  plane took  off at exactly 5  o'clock could be possible too or not

Comment: thank you so much for your detailed response. They are separate tense exercises without any text that is why it is a bit unclear when what happened